# Azure Devops trigger pipeline with pushing tags from Bitbucket

Tags: git, azure-devops, bitbucket, azure-pipelines

I am using BitBucket for my project and would like to know whether or not pushing tags can trigger pipeline from BitBucket. All the tutorials I saw are using Github. If anyone successfully did that with BitBucket, can you please give some advice? Thanks a lot

Here is my configuration of pipeline (following the discussion in https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/656727/build-pipeline-trigger-from-git-tag-is-not-working.html) trying to trigger with tag push

```
trigger:
  tags:
    include:
      - v*
      - refs/tags/v*
  branches:
    include:
      - refs/tags/v*
    exclude:
      - refs/heads/*
      - refs/remotes/*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to say that for Azure Devops, the tag of Bitbucket is belong to the external git tag. And until now, the CI triggers of Azure Devops does not work for External Git. The git polling job only retrieves refs that start with "**refs/heads**."

This is a good feature that should be achieve until now, but considering all the issues around polling the product group have, this is not high priority.

In our official Developer Community, there has one feature suggestion exists which converted from question: [External Git Pipeline Builds not being triggered for updates to tags](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/370285/pipeline-builds-not-being-triggered.html). You can vote and comment it. And when it has enough votes, the product group will consider it and will take it as plan.